# Uncaught TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am trying to create a HASH using crypto-js npm package and get this error

I am trying to create HASH For the simmple text and get the below TypeError.

**Uncaught TypeError: crypto.randomBytes is not a function**

```
// Includes crypto module 
var crypto = require('crypto');

// Difining algorithm 
const algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc'; 

// Defining key 
const key = crypto.randomBytes(32); 

// Defining iv 
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16); 

  
// An encrypt function 
function encrypt(text) { 
  
 // Creating Cipheriv with its parameter 
 let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv( 
      'aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(key), iv); 
  
 // Updating text 
 let encrypted = cipher.update(text); 
  
 // Using concatenation 
 encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]); 
  
 // Returning iv and encrypted data 
 return { iv: iv.toString('hex'),  
    encryptedData: encrypted.toString('hex') }; 
} 

// Displays output 
var output = encrypt("Please Encrypt This Message as SAFE"); 
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Sorry but your program is running like expected and shows **no** error - run the program live: https://repl.it/@javacrypto/Uncaught-TypeError-cryptorandomBytes-is-not-a-function#index.js so there is something wrong with your installation.